# How to summarize columns in joined tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables (students and account)
Every student has one record in students table but may be more than one record in the account table 
I need to summarize one column in the account table, grouped by students code in students table

I have written the following query but when I used the GROUP BY command it has returned an error:

```
select students.id,students.stcode,students.stname,account.stcode,
       sum(cast ((account.price) AS INT)) OVER () AS PriceTotal
from students 
inner join account on students.stcode=account.stcode 
group by students.stcode
```

**error message:**
`Column 'students.id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause`.

Comment: (1) this is mistagged MySQL. This is some other RDMS. (2) the error message explains what you did wrong. If you don't understand the error message go read about `GROUP BY`.

Comment: I don't see `students.id` in the query. Is the query up to date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to group by all columns that are not part of an aggregate. That said, if students.stname is functionally dependent of students.stcode (i.e. students.stcode is unique) you can apply a aggregate such as max on students.stcode. Since account.stcode = students.stcode that can be removed. I'm not sure what the over clause is supposed to do here so I removed that one, leaving us with:

```
select students.stcode, max(students.stname) as stname
     , sum(cast (account.price AS INT)) AS PriceTotal
from students 
join account 
    on students.stcode=account.stcode 
group by students.stcode
```

The other option is to include students.stname in the group by clause:

```
select students.stcode, students.stname
     , sum(cast (account.price AS INT)) AS PriceTotal
from students 
join account 
    on students.stcode=account.stcode 
group by students.stcode, students.stname
```

If you are using a DBMS with support for window functions (mysql which you tagged your post with does not) you don't need a group by:

```
select students.stcode, students.stname
     , sum(cast (account.price AS INT)) over () AS PriceTotal
from students 
join account 
    on students.stcode=account.stcode
```